# Trigger GitHub Actions workflow on all branches except when identical (after merge)?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

How can I setup a [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) workflow to [trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/configuring-a-workflow#triggering-a-workflow-with-events) when all branches are pushed, but only execute once if two branches are identical?

I have a git-flow-like workflow in my repo where there's a `develop` branch and release-specific branches. When I'm finished with a release, I merge it into `develop` and `master`

```
user@buskill:~repo$ git branch -l
  dev
  master
* v1.0.0
user@buskill:~repo$ git commit -am 'finished'
user@buskill:~repo$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
user@buskill:~repo$ git merge v1.0.0
...
user@buskill:~repo$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
user@buskill:~repo$ git merge v1.0.0
...
user@buskill:~repo$ git push
```

If I setup my app build CI process to trigger on pushes to all branches (which is what I want)

```
name: build
  
on:
  push
...
```

Then the above push results in three distinct jobs being executed. This, in fact, is wasteful since the merge means that all three branches are exactly the same so the builds will all produce exactly the same results.

Is it possible to setup a github workflow to trigger on pushes for all branches, except only execute once when pushing to multiple branches with identical contents?

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: what you're trying to achieve is similar to caching. If a branch is in a state that has already been built earlier, you wanna re-use the output of that earlier build - that's the equivalent of a cache hit.

Comment: If you're truly convinced that it's a worthwhile optimization, you can probably come up with some sort of caching mechanism that uses the state of a branch (e.g. hash of files) as a cache key. Be mindful of the pitfalls though. For instance, you'd have to invalidate your cache if the build process changes.